# Prestashop multistore - How to add JS code to head only for one shop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have PrestaShop™ 1.5.6.2 shop. I'm using multistore (two sites). I have to add some JS code to head section but only to one shop. Anybody knows how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Smarty in your theme (no override), in header.tpl :

```
{if $cart->id_shop==1}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{$js_dir}MyScript.js"></script>

{/if}
```

Insert this code in header. Change id_shop to the one you want to work on. MyScript.js file should be in /themes/MyTheme/js folder

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use this override code:

```
class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore {
    public function setMedia()
    {
        parent::setMedia();
        if ($this->context->shop->id == ID_OF_YOUR_SHOP) {
            $this->addJS(_THEME_JS_DIR_.'yourfile.js');
        }
    }
}
```

place it into override/classes/controller/FrontController.php and remember about deleting cache/class_index.php

This snippet will add yourfile.js if `id_shop = ID_OF_YOUR_SHOP`.

File is loaded from `themes/yourtheme/js/`.